# Как обнаружить утечки памяти?

Tags: c++, утечка-памяти

Знаете ли вы какие-нибудь эффективные инструменты для обнаружения утечек памяти в C++?

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

[О Valgrind на страницах Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).

[Руководство по Valgrind](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/).

[Джулин Сьюард. Valgrind 3.3 — Advanced Debugging and Profiling for GNU/Linux applications](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/valgrind/manual/).

Comment: ага, только под Windows это не работает...

Comment: В вопросе про Windows ничего нет. Но если нужно, то вот пара ссылок:

1. [Dr. Memory](http://code.google.com/p/drmemory/)
2. [D.U.M.A](http://duma.sourceforge.net/)

И даже плюшка для Visual Studio:  
[Visual Leak Detector for Visual C++ 2008/2010](http://vld.codeplex.com/)